# How to get an appConfig value into an object Scala/Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

i have been trying to achieve this for the better part of 2 days now and i keep hitting blockers, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Say i have an object

```
object myObject{
    val connectionString = (string from config file here)
}
```

How would i go about getting a string i have defined in appConfig into here, now that config has to be injected.

Thanks Jack

Comment: I guess you should have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you want to read configuration in some class say `UserService`

```
@Singleton
class UserService @Inject() (val configuration: Configuration) {
   val name = configuration.underlying.getString("hello")
}
```

*Note that the configuration file would be `application.conf` in this case*

**In application.conf**

```
name="something"
```

Don't use Scala object, use class with `Singleton` annotation with `Inject` annotation to inject configuration object into existing class.

Comment: Yes this works absolutely perfectly as it is, but if i try to inject this singleton class into another class using an injector (after i have bound this class to a trait) i get an error cannot find constructor for play.api.Configuration. I hope that makes sense and i know it is not part of the initial question.